# Reverse multiplication of 32-bit numbers

Tags: hash, bit-manipulation

I have two large signed 32-bit numbers (java ints) being multiplied together such that they'll overflow. Actually, I have one of the numbers, and the result. Can I determine what the other operand was?

`knownResult = unknownOperand * knownOperand;`

Why? I have a string and a suffix being hashed with fnv1a. I know the resulting hash and the suffix, I want to see how easy it is to determine the hash of the original string.

This is the core of fnv1a:

```
hash ^= byte
hash *= PRIME
```

Comment: Hmm, well you know that `MAX_INT` > `unknownOperand` > (`MAX_INT` / `knownOperand`)... trying to think if that gets you any closer. In the `fnv1a` algorithm, what are `byte` and `PRIME`? Are they configurable or constants? Hash functions are generally made to be collision resistant, but the existence of collisions implies that you can't be sure you've arrived at a unique answer.

Comment: byte is the input to the hash function, PRIME is a parameter to fnv1a, in this case it is `0x01000193`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends. If the multiplier is even, at least one bit must inevitably be lost. So I hope that prime isn't 2.

If it's odd, then you can absolutely reverse it, just multiply by the [modular multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of the multiplier to undo the multiplication.

There is an algorithm to calculate the modular multiplicative inverse modulo a power of two in Hacker's Delight.

For example, if the multiplier was `3`, then you'd multiply by `0xaaaaaaab` to undo (because `0xaaaaaaab * 3 = 1`). For `0x01000193`, the inverse is `0x359c449b`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to solve the equation `y = prime * x` for `x`, which you do by division in the finite ring modulo 2<sup>32</sup>: `x = y / prime`.

Technically you do that by multiplying `y` with the [multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of the prime modulo 2<sup>32</sup>, which can be computed by the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Uh, division? Or am I not understanding the question?

Comment: `(a * b) / b` does not equal `a` due to overflow of `(a * b)`. Edited question to clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the fastest method, but something very easy to memorise is this:

```
unsigned inv(unsigned x) {
  unsigned xx = x * x;
  while (xx != 1) {
    x *= xx;
    xx *= xx;
  }
  return x;
}
```

It returns `x**(2**n-1)` (as in `x*(x**2)*(x**4)*(x**8)*...`, or `x**(1+2+4+8+...)`).  As the loop exit condition implies, `x**(2**n)` is 1 when `n` is big enough, provided `x` is odd.

So, `x**(2**n-1)` equals `x**(2**n)/x` equals `1/x` equals the thing you multiply `x` by to get the value 1 (mod 2**n).  Which you then apply:

```
knownResult = unknownOperand * knownOperand
knownResult * inv(knownOperand) = unknownOperand * knownOperand * inv(knownOperand)
knownResult * inv(knownOperand) = unknownOperand * 1
```

or simply:

```
unknownOperand = knownResult * inv(knownOperand);
```

But there are faster ways, as given in other answers here.  This one's just easy to remember.

Also, obligatory SO "use a library function" answer: [BN_mod_inverse()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/BN_mod_inverse.html).